# Moniter folder permission

Tags: c#, security, file, directory, permissions

Anyone know how can we moniter file /folder permission on windows. Suppose a user can change the folder permission, the application can log the user, timing and other details.

If neone know third party tool/script for the same, plz suggest.

-Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to use the [`FileSystemWatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) class, which can raise an event when various properties of directories or files change. In your case, you want to insure you set the [`NotifyFilter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.notifyfilter.aspx) property to include the [`NotifyFilters.Security`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.notifyfilters.aspx) flag, which tells is to watch any permissions changes. Some good example code is given on the MSDN page, though `FileSystemWatcher` is really quite straightforward to use.

Comment: By this library i can know my file permission has changed. But how can i know which user changed permission and what was the time?

Answer (score 1):

Enable filesystem auditing, and set the SACL on a parent folder to audit permission and ownership changes. They will be reported in the System event log.